# How can i find a pattern in the AssemblyFile for a c# app using Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

The powershell script is as follows:

```
   $verNumber ="123"

# Replace last digit of AssemblyVersion

    $assemblyInfo = $assemblyInfo -replace "^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(`"([0-9]+)\. 
  ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+`"\)]", 
   ('[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$1.$2.$3.' + $verNumber + '")]')

    
   # Replace last digit of AssemblyFileVersion

   $assemblyInfo = $assemblyInfo -replace 
    "^\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(`"([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+`"\)]", 
    ('[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("$1.$2.$3.' + $verNumber + '")]')
```

This is what is in my file.

```
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.123")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.123")]
```

line 2 and 3 get updated but I am trying to update 1 , How can i get that pattern in the regex ?

Comment: Change `^\[` for `"^//\s*\[`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a simplified version of the regex you wanted to accomplish. See [this regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/qg6tgW/1) for details.

```sh
$verNumber = 123
$assemblyinfo = @'
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.123")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.123")]
'@

$assemblyinfo -replace '(?<=(^//\s*\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(\d+\.){3}))\d+', $verNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do all 3 replacements using 2 capture groups in a single replacement and an optional part in the pattern for the leading slashes and another optional part for the `File`

```
(?m)^((?:// )?\[assembly: Assembly(?:File)?Version\("(?:\d+\.){3})[0-9]+("\)])$
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?m)` Inline modifier for multiline
- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:// )?` Optionally match `//`
- `\[assembly: Assembly(?:File)?Version` Match `[assembly: AssemblyVersion` or `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion`
- `\("` Match `("`
- `(?:\d+\.){3}` Match 3 repetitions of 1+ digits 0-9 and a dot
- `)` Close group 1
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits that should be replaced
- `("\)])` Capture **group 2**, match `)]`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/enBbCi/1)

For example, reading a file.txt that contains the example strings:

```
$verNumber ="123"
$assemblyInfo = Get-Content -Raw file.txt
$assemblyInfo = $assemblyInfo -replace "(?m)^((?:// )?\[assembly: Assembly(?:File)?Version\(`"(?:\d+\.){3})[0-9]+(`"\)])$", "`${1}$verNumber`${2}"
Write-Output $assemblyInfo
```

Output

```
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.123")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.123")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.123")]
```